# Mix and match RxJava subscription threads

Tags: rx-java, rx-android

Is it possible to mix and match scheduler threads in RxJava. Basically I want to do something like the following on Android.

```
uiObservable
    .switchMap(o -> return anotherUIObservable)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .switchMap(o -> return networkObservable)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(result -> doSomething(result))
```

Is that possible within the same subscription ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's possible and really easy after you have fully understand the logic. But you probably confuse a bit observeOn() and subscribeOn() operators :)

```
uiObservable
    .switchMap(o -> return anotherUIObservable)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())  // means that the uiObservable and the switchMap above will run on the mainThread.

    .switchMap(o -> return networkObservable) //this will also run on the main thread

    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread()) // this does nothing as the above subscribeOn will overwrite this

    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // this means that the next operators (here only the subscribe will run on the mainThread
    .subscribe(result -> doSomething(result))
```

Maybe this is what you want:

```
uiObservable
    .switchMap(o -> return anotherUIObservable)
    .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // run the above on the main thread

    .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .switchMap(o -> return networkObservable) // run this on a new thread

    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) // run the subscribe on the mainThread
    .subscribe(result -> doSomething(result))
```

Bonus: I have written [a post](https://medium.com/@diolor/observe-in-the-correct-thread-1939bb9bb9d2) about these operators, hope it helps

Comment: Thanks !! I now have a bunch of follow up questions that I will be putting forth as and when I get the time.

Comment: @SaadFarooq feel free to ask :)